# jquery ui draggable - how can I prevent dragging outside the top of my document?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I've set up a jquery draggable, which can be moved around the entire document, it's not contained by anything, and this is acceptable, as when the user drags, I want them to be able to drag as far down the page (or left or right) as they wish.

Indeed, the only restriction I want - is that they should be prevented dragging the element outside of the top of the page.

**Is it possible to prevent dragging outside only one edge of a container?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could overwrite the position of the element being dragged.

This fiddle is an example of the position overwriting : http://jsbin.com/ufarif/7/edit

Here is an example to not permit to be more close than 80 px of the left border

```
$('[id^="drag-"]').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        cursorAt: { top: 15, left: 50 },        
        scroll: true,
        stop: function(){},  
        drag : function(e,ui){            
            //Do not permit to be more close than 80 px of the left border
            console.log(ui.position.left);      
            if(ui.position.left < 80)    
                ui.position.left = 80;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [containment](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) option to prevent dragging outside the window :

```
$("#id").draggable({
    handle: tr_top,
    containment: "window"
});
```